# Understanding the use of StatefulWidget in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, statefulwidget

I'm just starting to fiddle with Flutter and I can't understand the point of `StatefulWidget`. All those widgets do anywhere I've seen in tutorials etc. is instantiate a `State<MyWidget>` and let it do all the work.
For example, from [this](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) (official) tutorial:

```
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  ...
}
```

What I want to know is why is it built like that and what is the use of the outer class (in my example `RandomWords`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *"outer class"* is **`final`**, every widget is `final` (immutable). This means that all its *properties* have to be ***`final`*** as well:

```
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  @override
  createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  String name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    name = widget.name;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(name);

  void someMethod() {
    print(widget.name);
    setState(() => name = 'new name');
  }
}
```

From the *`State`* all fields of the ***`StatefulWidget`*** can be accessed and obviously **not** changed *because they are `final`*.

`State`'s, however, can *change data*. ***`setState`*** will execute its callback and then *rebuild* the `State` (with the new data).

`StatelessWidget`'s can also be rebuilt, i.e. when its parent is rebuilding, but all state is lost and no data is kept. That is what `State`'s are being used for.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter to build the UI, we use two main types of widgets, **StatelessWidget** and **StatefulWidget.** The stateful widget is used when the values (state) of a widget changes or has a mutable state that can change over time.

Some important **properties of stateful** widgets

- A Stateful widget is mutable. It keeps track of the state.
- A Stateful widget’s build() method is called multiple times.
- It rebuilds several times over its lifetime.

Some **examples of stateful** widgets

- Checkbox: Keeps its state whether a checkbox is checked or not.
- Radio: Keep its state if it’s selected or not.

  ```
  class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
    }

  class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
  }
  }
  ```

The stateful widget is declared with two classes, the **StatefulWidget class** and the **State class**. The StatefulWidget class is rebuilt when the widget’s configuration changes, but the State class can persist (remain).

For example, when the state changes, the widget is rebuilt. If the StatefulWidget is removed from the tree and then inserted back into the tree some time later,then a new State object is created.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it's to save information about the widget. So you implement setState everytime you want to save a variable or something. See the tutorial about adding interactivity in Flutter.

Comment: Why do I need two classes?

Answer (score 0):

stateless widget is like constant display,
like only to display something
stateful is for changable display, i mean if any value has to change in that screen then it should be stateful